# Random selection of sample from CSV file with dask different than with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, indexing, dask

I have 3 big CSV files. I try to randomly extract some samples from the files without loading them into the memory. I am doing this:

```
SITS = dd.read_csv("sits_train_0.csv", blocksize="512MB",
                   usecols=band_blue + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")
MASK = dd.read_csv("mask_train_0.csv", blocksize="512MB",
                   usecols=band_mask + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")
GP = dd.read_csv("sits_gp_train_0.csv", blocksize="512MB",
                 usecols=band_blue_gp + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")

# SITS = pd.read_csv("sits_train_0.csv",
#                    usecols=band_blue + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")
# MASK = pd.read_csv("mask_train_0.csv",
#                    usecols=band_mask + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")
# GP = pd.read_csv("sits_gp_train_0.csv",
#                  usecols=band_blue_gp + ["samplefid"]).set_index("samplefid")

np.random.seed(0)
NSAMPLES=100
samples = np.random.choice(MASK.index, size=NSAMPLES, replace=False)

s = SITS.loc[samples][band_blue].compute().values
m = MASK.loc[samples][band_mask].compute().values
sg = GP.loc[samples][band_blue_gp].compute().values

# s = SITS.loc[samples][band_blue].values
# m = MASK.loc[samples][band_mask].values
# sg = GP.loc[samples][band_blue_gp].values
```

I had strange results, so I compare to pandas with smaller files (see commented code above) for which I have correct results.

If I set blocksize to None, the results are fine, but it loads everything in memory, so using dask is not useful in that case and my CSV are to big to fits in memory. My CSV are written randomly so I need to use index to recover the same samples from the 3 CSV.

I feel I miss something from dask, but I don't see what.

Comment: By "strange results", I mean that samples from s,m and sg does not correspond with dask while I am using .loc with the same "samples" id. The first one (s[0,:] ) is ok with the others (m[0,:]and sg[0,:]) but the remaining (s[1:, :]) are not ok. 
With pandas, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [sample](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.sample)

```py
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [18]: df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
    ...:                    'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
    ...:                    'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
    ...:                   index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

In [19]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [20]: ddf.sample??

In [21]: df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1)
Out[21]:
      num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
dog          4          0                  2
fish         0          0                  8

In [22]: ddf.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1)
Out[22]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              num_legs num_wings num_specimen_seen
npartitions=2
dog              int64     int64             int64
fish               ...       ...               ...
spider             ...       ...               ...
Dask Name: sample, 4 tasks

In [23]: ddf.sample(frac=0.5, replace=True, random_state=1).compute()
Out[23]:
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
fish           0          0                  8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @quasiben, it works. I change the sampling part to:  

`NSAMPLES=100`  
`FRAC = NSAMPLES / SITS.shape[0].compute()`  

`s = SITS.sample(frac=FRAC, replace=False, random_state=0).compute()`  
`m = MASK.loc[s.index.values][band_mask].compute()`  
`sg = GP.loc[s.index.values][band_blue_gp].compute()`  

and I finally get a correct match between rows with same index. Yet, it is not clear why the first version of the code does not work.